# PHP mysqli prepare statement noget working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi hope you can help me :)

I have a function and it has worked in the past but this time I get a wired behavior..

It returns e.commenttime but nothing else..

```
function Get_Comment($mysqli, $event_id){
  if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT e.text, e.commenttime, m.username FROM eventcomment e INNER JOIN members m ON e.memberid = m.id WHERE e.eventid =$event_id ORDER BY e.commenttime ")); {
    $stmt->bind_result($comment, $commenttime, $commentuser);
    // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->execute();
        //grab a result set
    $resultSet = $stmt->get_result();

        // Returning array
  $events = array();

       // Fetch results
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $e = array();
    $e['comment'] = $row['comment'];
    $e['commenttime'] = $row['commenttime'];
    $e['commentuser'] = $row['commentuser'];
    // Merge the event array into the return array
    array_push($events, $e);
  // print_r($e);
  }
  // return array"
  return $events;
}
}
```

to be sure that the data is sound i ran via phpMyAdmin

> SELECT e.text, e.commenttime, m.username FROM eventcomment e INNER
>   JOIN members m ON e.memberid = m.id WHERE e.eventid =15 ORDER BY
>   e.commenttime

Here it returned the full data for all fields..

Best Regards 
Bjarke

Comment: Print_r returns `Array ( [0] => Array ( [comment] => [commenttime] => 2014-07-13 00:00:00 [commentuser] => ) [1] => Array ( [comment] => [commenttime] => 2014-07-13 01:00:00 [commentuser] => ) [2] => Array ( [comment] => [commenttime] => 2014-07-14 20:44:00 [commentuser] => ) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only problem is that the array keys you are using do not match the column names from the query. You're only getting commenttime because that is the only one that *does* match.

You can edit the keys to `$row` to match the column names in your query like this:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $e = array();
    $e['comment'] = $row['text'];
    $e['commenttime'] = $row['commenttime'];
    $e['commentuser'] = $row['username'];
```

also, it looks like you are binding results to variables and then not using them. If you are getting all your values from the array you have fetched, then I don't think

```
$stmt->bind_result($comment, $commenttime, $commentuser);
```

is actually necessary.